# inserting Radio Button value into SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress, forms

I have this form area:

```
 <table width="200" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
         <td><label class="form_text">
            <input type="radio" name="date_pref" value="gregorian" id="date_pref-0">&nbsp; Gregorian</label>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td><label class="form_text">
                <input type="radio" name="date_pref" value="hebrew" id="date_pref-1">&nbsp; Hebrew</label>
           </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

and the PhP to insert into the SQL table is

```
 <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $email=$_POST['cemail'];
            $password=$_POST['cpass'];
            $cname=$_POST['cname'];
            $dname=$_POST['dname'];
            $dateeng=$_POST['dateenglish'];
            $datehebrew=$_POST['datehebrew'];
            $date_pref=$_POST['date_pref'];
            }

 $table_name='candle_number';

            $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array
  ( 'userid' => $user_id, 'dname' => $dname ,'dateenglish' =>
  $dateeng,'datehebrew' => $datehebrew, 'dateformat' => $date_pref ));
```

But what is happening now is no result is created. I THINK maybe I am not formatting the radio result correctly for the SQL, but I cannot seem to find a concise answer. the SQL row is formatted as VARCHAR. Any help would be great.

EDIT: The SQL row is

```
 date format  VARCHAR(10) NULL
```

Comment: Can you post the table definition?  Perhaps you are leaving out some non-nullable columns in your insert statement?

Comment: Based on the snippet of HTML, it seems like `$_POST` would have a member with the name of the radio button input  (`name="date_pref"`) i.e. **`$_POST['date_pref']`**,  but I'm not seeing a reference to that.

Comment: why both mysql and sql-server tags, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It's my first real back-end project. It's probably not 100% accurate, and I am kind of learning on the fly.

Comment: Why negative 2 on the down votes?

Comment: yes but for this it has to be stored that way.

Comment: Well the user has to choose one, so is that correct?

Comment: Oh i see its not a date and its not a checkbox. My mistake

Comment: The date has to be that way because of hebrew conversion. It's a radio checkbox. I think it has to do with the array

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Just a matter of the right $_POST['date_pref']

Answer (score 0):

When posting, it is important to know that you need the name attributes.
So relating to your issue, a simple `$_POST['date_pref'];` should be sufficient enough